# What defines "ll" in Fedora?

Tags: bash, fedora, ls

In Fedora, instead of typing `ls -l`, you can type `ll`. What causes this behavior?  I've installed a new Debian system that does not appear to have this functionality. They're both running Bash. I can define an alias for `alias ll=ls -l`, but I'm wondering what the root difference is between these two bashes.

Comment: As a side note, to stay universal across different Linux/Unix distributions it is better to stick to default commands that work everywhere without extra effort. And `ls -l` command is very short anyway so `ll` doesn't add much value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `Fedora` `/etc/bashrc`:

```
    for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "$PS1" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
    done
```

And in `/etc/profile.d` are files in which are defined aliases. `ll` is defined in `/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh`

Answer (score 4):

Check out `type ll` to see :) On Fedora you're likely to get something like `ll is an alias for ls -l`, which would mean that Fedora just comes preconfigured with the same alias you've mentioned.

Comment: Cool. I don't have a Fedora machine at the moment. Have you tried it on a Fedora machine and is that the output you get?

Comment: No, that's on an old LMDE (Debian-based) machine with `zsh`. Actually I'm using `oh-my-zsh` with its default aliases turned on.

Comment: Here it is on Fedora 21: `type ll` Output= ll is aliased to `ls -l --color=auto'